# Calculation of a symbolic expression in SymPy and convert them to numeric within Julia

Tags: python, julia, sympy

I am trying to convert a piece of python code to Julia 1.1.0. 
The python code:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
x, y = sp.symbols('x y')
data = np.random.randn(1000, 2)
a,b = data[:,0], data[:,1]
M = len(data[:,0]) 
m = 5
n = round(m*(m+1)/2) 
L = np.zeros((M,n)) 
l = sp.zeros(1,n)
k = 0
for i in range(1,m+1):
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        l[0,k]=((i-j)*(i-j-1)*x**(i-j-2)*y**(j-1))

        f = sp.lambdify([x,y], l[0,k], "numpy")
        L[:,k] = np.squeeze(f(a,b))
        k=k+1
```

and my attempt of Julia code:

```
using SymPy
data = rand(1000,2)
a = data[:,1];
b = data[:,2];
M = length(data[:,1]) 
x = symbols("x");
y = symbols("y");
m = 5;
n = Int(m*(m+1)/2) 
L = zeros(M,n)
l = zeros(1,n)
k = 1;
for i in 1:m
      for j in 1:i
            l[1,k] = ((i-j)*(i-j-1)*x^(i-j-2)*y^(j-1))
            f = l[1,k]
            L[:,k] = f.subs([(x, a), (y, b)])
            k=k+1  
    end
end
```

when I runJulia codes, for `l[1,k]` I got following error

```
DomainError with -2:
Cannot raise an integer x to a negative power -2.
Convert input to float.
Stacktrace:
 [1] throw_domerr_powbysq(::Sym, ::Int64) at ./intfuncs.jl:173
 [2] power_by_squaring(::Sym, ::Int64) at ./intfuncs.jl:196
 [3] ^(::Sym, ::Int64) at ./intfuncs.jl:221
 [4] top-level scope at ./In[80]:14
```

Also, I am not sure about the following codes

```
    f = l[1,k]
    L[:,k] = f.subs([(x, a), (y, b)])
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me to translate python codes to julia codes.

**Update:**

Based on the post of @jverzani I can now convert sym values to float with following codes

```
using SymPy
data = rand(1000,2)
a = data[:,1];
b = data[:,2];
M = length(data[:,1])
x = symbols("x");
y = symbols("y");
m = 5;
n = Int(m*(m+1)/2)
LL = zeros(M,n)
L = zeros(Sym, M,n)
l = zeros(Sym, 1,n)
k = 1;
for i in 1:m
      for j in 1:i
            l[1,k] = ((i-j)*(i-j-1)*x^Sym(i-j-2)*y^Sym(j-1))
            f = l[1,k]
            L[:,k] .= f.subs([(x, a), (y, b)])
            global k=k+1
    end
end
for s in 1:M
    for r in 1:n
        LL[s,r] = float(subs(L[s,r],(x,a[s]),(y,b[s])))
    end
end
```

But this time the codes are very slow. How can I optimize the codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SymPy just got a major change, inherited from `PyCall`, which makes the last bit with `subs` work as typed.

As for the first one, you are bumping into a Julia issue with integer bases and non-literal, negative integer powers. You can modify that line to make the powers symbolic, such as `x^Sym(i-j-2)` in place of `x^(i-j-2)`. (It might be best to bypass this.)

The following edit tries to mirror the spirit of the Python code. It wraps into a function to test speed on size of `N` and avoid the need for `global` on the `k` assignment.

```
using SymPy
import PyCall
np = PyCall.pyimport("numpy") #import numpy as np
const sp = sympy 



function fill_L(N=1000)

    x, y = sp.symbols("x y")
    offset = 1
    data = np.random.randn(N, 2)
    a,b = data[:,0+offset], data[:,1+offset]
    M = length(data[:,0+offset])
    m = 5
    n = round(Int, m*(m+1)/2)
    L = np.zeros((M,n))
    l = sp.zeros(1,n)
    k = 0
    for i in 1:m
        for j in 1:i
            l[1,k+offset]=((i-j)*Sym(i-j-1)*x^Sym(i-j-2)*y^Sym(j-1))
            f = lambdify(l[1,k+offset], (x, y))
            #f = sp.lambdify([x,y], l[0,k], "numpy")
            L[:,k+offset] = f.(a,b)
            k=k+1
        end
    end
    L
end
```

Performance is reasonable now, due to the broadcasting of `f` above.

Comment: I run your codes but I think f.subs() does not work. Because the results still contain x and y

Comment: Try `subs(f, x=>a, y=>b)`, that should also work. (The dot-call syntax is relatively recent and requires an updated `PyCall` and `SymPy` to work.

Comment: Updating is a good idea, as now much of the syntax can be carried over. E.g, try `using PyCall; np=pyimport("np"); ...; L=np.zeros((M,n))` or `const sp=SymPy.sympy; l = sp.zeros(1,n)`

Comment: thank you for your help but when I try subs(f,x=>a,y=>b), I got following error:

Comment: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,1} to an object of type Sym
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{Sym}, !Matched::Complex{BigFloat}) at /home/user/.julia/packages/SymPy/4aR3F/src/types.jl:69
  convert(::Type{Sym}, !Matched::Complex) at /home/user/.julia/packages/SymPy/4aR3F/src/types.jl:81
  convert(::Type{Sym}, !Matched::AbstractString) at /home/user/.julia/packages/SymPy/4aR3F/src/types.jl:89
  ...

Comment: Which line is this?  It is a shape mismatch issue.

Comment: When I use `L[:,k] .= subs(f, x=>a, y=>b)` instead of `L[:,k] .= f.subs([(x, a), (y, b)])` the error occurs. I think the error occurs due to array substitution for example if I use `L[:,k] .= subs(f, x=>1, y=>5)` it works but when I use the arrays `a` and `b` it does not work.

Comment: Try “subs.” It might broadcast well over the pairs. If not some syntax will work.

Comment: For speedup, you might follow the original. It might be beneficial to lambdify your function then evaluate, rather than symbolically substitute. That is replace `f.subs([(x, a), (y, b)])` with `lambdify(f, (x,y))(a, b)`. There is overhead in lambdify, so this is best if the function can be reused, as is the case you have with your inner loop.

Comment: If I use `lambdify(f, (x,y))(a, b)`  I get a new error:
`MethodError: no method matching ^(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  ^(!Matched::Float16, ::Integer) at math.jl:795
  ^(!Matched::Missing, ::Integer) at missing.jl:124
  ^(!Matched::Missing, ::Number) at missing.jl:97
  ...`

Comment: But I do not understand offset. Why simply not `data[:,1]` but `data[:,0+offset]` ?